# Arduino code "... was not declared in this scope" with STM32

Tags: arduino, stm32, arduino-ide

I want to use arduino code with STM32 in Arduino IDE, but I get an error:

> sketch_apr28a:509: error: 'REG_PMC_PCER1' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:510: error: 'REG_PIOC_PDR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:511: error: 'REG_PIOC_ABSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:512: error: 'REG_PWM_CLK' was not declared in this scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:513: error: 'REG_PWM_CMR6' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:514: error: 'REG_PWM_CPRD6' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:515: error: 'REG_PWM_CDTY6' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:516: error: 'REG_PWM_ENA' was not declared in this scope
>
> \Ver 1\sketch_apr28a\sketch_apr28a.ino: In function 'void
>   captureImg(uint16_t, uint16_t)':
>
> sketch_apr28a:534: error: 'REG_PIOB_PDSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:535: error: 'REG_PIOB_PDSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:541: error: 'REG_PIOD_PDSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:542: error: 'REG_PIOC_PDSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:543: error: 'REG_PIOD_PDSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:544: error: 'REG_PIOD_PDSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:545: error: 'REG_PIOD_PDSR' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> \Ver 1\sketch_apr28a\sketch_apr28a.ino: In function 'int
>   uart_putchar(uint8_t)':
>
> sketch_apr28a:570: error: 'UART' was not declared in this scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:570: error: 'UART_SR_TXRDY' was not declared in this
>   scope
>
> sketch_apr28a:571: error: 'UART' was not declared in this scope
>
> exit status 1 'REG_PMC_PCER1' was not declared in this scope"

What should I do?

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define address  (0x42 >> 1)

#define vga   0
#define qvga  1
#define qqvga   2
#define yuv422  0
#define rgb565  1
#define bayerRGB  2

/* Registers */
#define REG_GAIN    0x00  /* Gain lower 8 bits (rest in vref) */
#define REG_BLUE    0x01  /* blue gain */
#define REG_RED       0x02  /* red gain */
#define REG_VREF    0x03  /* Pieces of GAIN, VSTART, VSTOP */
#define REG_COM1    0x04  /* Control 1 */
#define COM1_CCIR656  0x40    /* CCIR656 enable */

#define REG_BAVE    0x05  /* U/B Average level */
#define REG_GbAVE   0x06  /* Y/Gb Average level */
#define REG_AECHH   0x07  /* AEC MS 5 bits */
#define REG_RAVE    0x08  /* V/R Average level */
#define REG_COM2    0x09  /* Control 2 */
#define COM2_SSLEEP         0x10  /* Soft sleep mode */
#define REG_PID           0x0a  /* Product ID MSB */
#define REG_VER           0x0b  /* Product ID LSB */
#define REG_COM3    0x0c  /* Control 3 */
#define COM3_SWAP         0x40  /* Byte swap */
#define COM3_SCALEEN          0x08  /* Enable scaling */
#define COM3_DCWEN          0x04  /* Enable downsamp/crop/window */
#define REG_COM4    0x0d  /* Control 4 */
#define REG_COM5    0x0e  /* All "reserved" */
#define REG_COM6    0x0f  /* Control 6 */
#define REG_AECH    0x10  /* More bits of AEC value */
#define REG_CLKRC   0x11  /* Clocl control */
#define CLK_EXT           0x40  /* Use external clock directly */
#define CLK_SCALE   0x3f  /* Mask for internal clock scale */
#define REG_COM7    0x12  /* Control 7 */ //REG mean address.
#define COM7_RESET          0x80  /* Register reset */
#define COM7_FMT_MASK         0x38
#define COM7_FMT_VGA          0x00
#define COM7_FMT_CIF          0x20  /* CIF format */
#define COM7_FMT_QVGA         0x10  /* QVGA format */
#define COM7_FMT_QCIF         0x08  /* QCIF format */
#define COM7_RGB          0x04  /* bits 0 and 2 - RGB format */
#define COM7_YUV          0x00  /* YUV */
#define COM7_BAYER          0x01  /* Bayer format */
#define COM7_PBAYER         0x05  /* "Processed bayer" */
#define REG_COM8    0x13  /* Control 8 */
#define COM8_FASTAEC          0x80  /* Enable fast AGC/AEC */
#define COM8_AECSTEP          0x40  /* Unlimited AEC step size */
#define COM8_BFILT    0x20  /* Band filter enable */
#define COM8_AGC    0x04  /* Auto gain enable */
#define COM8_AWB    0x02  /* White balance enable */
#define COM8_AEC    0x01  /* Auto exposure enable */
#define REG_COM9    0x14  /* Control 9- gain ceiling */
#define REG_COM10   0x15  /* Control 10 */
#define COM10_HSYNC         0x40  /* HSYNC instead of HREF */
#define COM10_PCLK_HB         0x20  /* Suppress PCLK on horiz blank */
#define COM10_HREF_REV          0x08  /* Reverse HREF */
#define COM10_VS_LEAD         0x04  /* VSYNC on clock leading edge */
#define COM10_VS_NEG          0x02  /* VSYNC negative */
#define COM10_HS_NEG          0x01  /* HSYNC negative */
#define REG_HSTART    0x17  /* Horiz start high bits */
#define REG_HSTOP   0x18  /* Horiz stop high bits */
#define REG_VSTART    0x19  /* Vert start high bits */
#define REG_VSTOP   0x1a  /* Vert stop high bits */
#define REG_PSHFT   0x1b  /* Pixel delay after HREF */
#define REG_MIDH    0x1c  /* Manuf. ID high */
#define REG_MIDL    0x1d  /* Manuf. ID low */
#define REG_MVFP    0x1e  /* Mirror / vflip */
#define MVFP_MIRROR         0x20  /* Mirror image */
#define MVFP_FLIP   0x10  /* Vertical flip */

#define REG_AEW           0x24  /* AGC upper limit */
#define REG_AEB           0x25    /* AGC lower limit */
#define REG_VPT           0x26  /* AGC/AEC fast mode op region */
#define REG_HSYST   0x30  /* HSYNC rising edge delay */
#define REG_HSYEN   0x31  /* HSYNC falling edge delay */
#define REG_HREF    0x32  /* HREF pieces */
#define REG_TSLB    0x3a  /* lots of stuff */
#define TSLB_YLAST    0x04  /* UYVY or VYUY - see com13 */
#define REG_COM11   0x3b  /* Control 11 */
#define COM11_NIGHT         0x80  /* NIght mode enable */
#define COM11_NMFR          0x60  /* Two bit NM frame rate */
#define COM11_HZAUTO          0x10  /* Auto detect 50/60 Hz */
#define COM11_50HZ          0x08  /* Manual 50Hz select */
#define COM11_EXP   0x02
#define REG_COM12   0x3c  /* Control 12 */
#define COM12_HREF          0x80  /* HREF always */
#define REG_COM13   0x3d  /* Control 13 */
#define COM13_GAMMA         0x80  /* Gamma enable */
#define COM13_UVSAT         0x40  /* UV saturation auto adjustment */
#define COM13_UVSWAP          0x01  /* V before U - w/TSLB */
#define REG_COM14   0x3e  /* Control 14 */
#define COM14_DCWEN         0x10  /* DCW/PCLK-scale enable */
#define REG_EDGE    0x3f  /* Edge enhancement factor */
#define REG_COM15   0x40  /* Control 15 */
#define COM15_R10F0         0x00  /* Data range 10 to F0 */
#define COM15_R01FE         0x80  /*      01 to FE */
#define COM15_R00FF         0xc0  /*      00 to FF */
#define COM15_RGB565          0x10  /* RGB565 output */
#define COM15_RGB555          0x30  /* RGB555 output */
#define REG_COM16   0x41  /* Control 16 */
#define COM16_AWBGAIN         0x08  /* AWB gain enable */
#define REG_COM17   0x42  /* Control 17 */
#define COM17_AECWIN          0xc0  /* AEC window - must match COM4 */
#define COM17_CBAR          0x08  /* DSP Color bar */
/*
* This matrix defines how the colors are generated, must be
* tweaked to adjust hue and saturation.
*
* Order: v-red, v-green, v-blue, u-red, u-green, u-blue
* They are nine-bit signed quantities, with the sign bit
* stored in0x58.Sign for v-red is bit 0, and up from there.
*/
#define REG_CMATRIX_BASE  0x4f
#define CMATRIX_LEN           6
#define REG_CMATRIX_SIGN  0x58
#define REG_BRIGHT    0x55  /* Brightness */
#define REG_CONTRAS         0x56  /* Contrast control */
#define REG_GFIX    0x69  /* Fix gain control */
#define REG_REG76   0x76  /* OV's name */
#define R76_BLKPCOR         0x80  /* Black pixel correction enable */
#define R76_WHTPCOR         0x40  /* White pixel correction enable */
#define REG_RGB444          0x8c  /* RGB 444 control */
#define R444_ENABLE         0x02  /* Turn on RGB444, overrides 5x5 */
#define R444_RGBX   0x01  /* Empty nibble at end */
#define REG_HAECC1    0x9f  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 1 */
#define REG_HAECC2    0xa0  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 2 */
#define REG_BD50MAX         0xa5  /* 50hz banding step limit */
#define REG_HAECC3    0xa6  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 3 */
#define REG_HAECC4    0xa7  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 4 */
#define REG_HAECC5    0xa8  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 5 */
#define REG_HAECC6    0xa9  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 6 */
#define REG_HAECC7    0xaa  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 7 */
#define REG_BD60MAX         0xab  /* 60hz banding step limit */
#define REG_GAIN    0x00  /* Gain lower 8 bits (rest in vref) */
#define REG_BLUE    0x01  /* blue gain */
#define REG_RED           0x02  /* red gain */
#define REG_VREF    0x03  /* Pieces of GAIN, VSTART, VSTOP */
#define REG_COM1    0x04  /* Control 1 */
#define COM1_CCIR656          0x40  /* CCIR656 enable */
#define REG_BAVE    0x05  /* U/B Average level */
#define REG_GbAVE   0x06  /* Y/Gb Average level */
#define REG_AECHH   0x07  /* AEC MS 5 bits */
#define REG_RAVE    0x08  /* V/R Average level */
#define REG_COM2    0x09  /* Control 2 */
#define COM2_SSLEEP         0x10  /* Soft sleep mode */
#define REG_PID           0x0a  /* Product ID MSB */
#define REG_VER           0x0b  /* Product ID LSB */
#define REG_COM3    0x0c  /* Control 3 */
#define COM3_SWAP         0x40  /* Byte swap */
#define COM3_SCALEEN          0x08  /* Enable scaling */
#define COM3_DCWEN          0x04  /* Enable downsamp/crop/window */
#define REG_COM4    0x0d  /* Control 4 */
#define REG_COM5    0x0e  /* All "reserved" */
#define REG_COM6    0x0f  /* Control 6 */
#define REG_AECH    0x10  /* More bits of AEC value */
#define REG_CLKRC   0x11  /* Clocl control */
#define CLK_EXT           0x40  /* Use external clock directly */
#define CLK_SCALE   0x3f  /* Mask for internal clock scale */
#define REG_COM7    0x12  /* Control 7 */
#define COM7_RESET          0x80  /* Register reset */
#define COM7_FMT_MASK         0x38
#define COM7_FMT_VGA          0x00
#define COM7_FMT_CIF          0x20  /* CIF format */
#define COM7_FMT_QVGA         0x10  /* QVGA format */
#define COM7_FMT_QCIF         0x08  /* QCIF format */
#define COM7_RGB    0x04  /* bits 0 and 2 - RGB format */
#define COM7_YUV    0x00  /* YUV */
#define COM7_BAYER          0x01  /* Bayer format */
#define COM7_PBAYER         0x05  /* "Processed bayer" */
#define REG_COM8    0x13  /* Control 8 */
#define COM8_FASTAEC          0x80  /* Enable fast AGC/AEC */
#define COM8_AECSTEP          0x40  /* Unlimited AEC step size */
#define COM8_BFILT    0x20  /* Band filter enable */
#define COM8_AGC    0x04  /* Auto gain enable */
#define COM8_AWB    0x02  /* White balance enable */
#define COM8_AEC    0x01  /* Auto exposure enable */
#define REG_COM9    0x14  /* Control 9- gain ceiling */
#define REG_COM10   0x15  /* Control 10 */
#define COM10_HSYNC         0x40  /* HSYNC instead of HREF */
#define COM10_PCLK_HB         0x20  /* Suppress PCLK on horiz blank */
#define COM10_HREF_REV          0x08  /* Reverse HREF */
#define COM10_VS_LEAD           0x04  /* VSYNC on clock leading edge */
#define COM10_VS_NEG          0x02  /* VSYNC negative */
#define COM10_HS_NEG          0x01  /* HSYNC negative */
#define REG_HSTART    0x17  /* Horiz start high bits */
#define REG_HSTOP   0x18  /* Horiz stop high bits */
#define REG_VSTART    0x19  /* Vert start high bits */
#define REG_VSTOP   0x1a  /* Vert stop high bits */
#define REG_PSHFT   0x1b  /* Pixel delay after HREF */
#define REG_MIDH    0x1c  /* Manuf. ID high */
#define REG_MIDL    0x1d  /* Manuf. ID low */
#define REG_MVFP    0x1e  /* Mirror / vflip */
#define MVFP_MIRROR         0x20  /* Mirror image */
#define MVFP_FLIP   0x10  /* Vertical flip */
#define REG_AEW           0x24  /* AGC upper limit */
#define REG_AEB           0x25  /* AGC lower limit */
#define REG_VPT           0x26  /* AGC/AEC fast mode op region */
#define REG_HSYST   0x30  /* HSYNC rising edge delay */
#define REG_HSYEN   0x31  /* HSYNC falling edge delay */
#define REG_HREF    0x32  /* HREF pieces */
#define REG_TSLB    0x3a  /* lots of stuff */
#define TSLB_YLAST    0x04  /* UYVY or VYUY - see com13 */
#define REG_COM11   0x3b  /* Control 11 */
#define COM11_NIGHT         0x80  /* NIght mode enable */
#define COM11_NMFR          0x60  /* Two bit NM frame rate */
#define COM11_HZAUTO          0x10  /* Auto detect 50/60 Hz */
#define COM11_50HZ          0x08  /* Manual 50Hz select */
#define COM11_EXP   0x02
#define REG_COM12   0x3c  /* Control 12 */
#define COM12_HREF          0x80  /* HREF always */
#define REG_COM13   0x3d  /* Control 13 */
#define COM13_GAMMA         0x80  /* Gamma enable */
#define COM13_UVSAT         0x40  /* UV saturation auto adjustment */
#define COM13_UVSWAP          0x01  /* V before U - w/TSLB */
#define REG_COM14   0x3e  /* Control 14 */
#define COM14_DCWEN         0x10  /* DCW/PCLK-scale enable */
#define REG_EDGE    0x3f  /* Edge enhancement factor */
#define REG_COM15   0x40  /* Control 15 */
#define COM15_R10F0         0x00  /* Data range 10 to F0 */
#define COM15_R01FE         0x80  /*      01 to FE */
#define COM15_R00FF         0xc0  /*      00 to FF */
#define COM15_RGB565          0x10  /* RGB565 output */
#define COM15_RGB555          0x30  /* RGB555 output */
#define REG_COM16   0x41  /* Control 16 */
#define COM16_AWBGAIN         0x08  /* AWB gain enable */
#define REG_COM17   0x42  /* Control 17 */
#define COM17_AECWIN          0xc0  /* AEC window - must match COM4 */
#define COM17_CBAR          0x08  /* DSP Color bar */

#define CMATRIX_LEN             6
#define REG_BRIGHT    0x55  /* Brightness */
#define REG_REG76   0x76  /* OV's name */
#define R76_BLKPCOR         0x80  /* Black pixel correction enable */
#define R76_WHTPCOR         0x40  /* White pixel correction enable */
#define REG_RGB444          0x8c  /* RGB 444 control */
#define R444_ENABLE         0x02  /* Turn on RGB444, overrides 5x5 */
#define R444_RGBX   0x01  /* Empty nibble at end */
#define REG_HAECC1    0x9f  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 1 */
#define REG_HAECC2    0xa0  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 2 */
#define REG_BD50MAX         0xa5  /* 50hz banding step limit */
#define REG_HAECC3    0xa6  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 3 */
#define REG_HAECC4    0xa7  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 4 */
#define REG_HAECC5    0xa8  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 5 */
#define REG_HAECC6    0xa9  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 6 */
#define REG_HAECC7    0xaa  /* Hist AEC/AGC control 7 */
#define REG_BD60MAX         0xab  /* 60hz banding step limit */
#define MTX1            0x4f  /* Matrix Coefficient 1 */
#define MTX2            0x50  /* Matrix Coefficient 2 */
#define MTX3            0x51  /* Matrix Coefficient 3 */
#define MTX4            0x52  /* Matrix Coefficient 4 */
#define MTX5            0x53  /* Matrix Coefficient 5 */
#define MTX6            0x54  /* Matrix Coefficient 6 */
#define REG_CONTRAS         0x56  /* Contrast control */
#define MTXS            0x58  /* Matrix Coefficient Sign */
#define AWBC7           0x59  /* AWB Control 7 */
#define AWBC8           0x5a  /* AWB Control 8 */
#define AWBC9           0x5b  /* AWB Control 9 */
#define AWBC10            0x5c  /* AWB Control 10 */
#define AWBC11            0x5d  /* AWB Control 11 */
#define AWBC12            0x5e  /* AWB Control 12 */
#define REG_GFI           0x69  /* Fix gain control */
#define GGAIN           0x6a  /* G Channel AWB Gain */
#define DBLV            0x6b  
#define AWBCTR3           0x6c  /* AWB Control 3 */
#define AWBCTR2           0x6d  /* AWB Control 2 */
#define AWBCTR1           0x6e  /* AWB Control 1 */
#define AWBCTR0           0x6f  /* AWB Control 0 */



struct regval_list{
  uint8_t reg_num;
  uint8_t value;
};

uint8_t myImage[240][320];

const struct regval_list qvga_ov7670[] PROGMEM = {
  { REG_COM14, 0x19 },
  { 0x72, 0x11 },
  { 0x73, 0xf1 },

  { REG_HSTART, 0x16 },
  { REG_HSTOP, 0x04 },
  { REG_HREF, 0xF6 },
  { REG_VSTART, 0x02 },
  { REG_VSTOP, 0x7a },
  { REG_VREF, 0x0a },

  { 0xff, 0xff }, /* END MARKER */
};

const struct regval_list yuv422_ov7670[] PROGMEM = {
  { REG_COM7, 0x0 },  /* Selects YUV mode */
  { REG_RGB444, 0 },  /* No RGB444 please */
  { REG_COM1, 0 },
  { REG_COM15, COM15_R00FF },
  { REG_COM9, 0x6A }, /* 128x gain ceiling; 0x8 is reserved bit */
  { 0x4f, 0x80 },   /* "matrix coefficient 1" */
  { 0x50, 0x80 },   /* "matrix coefficient 2" */
  { 0x51, 0 },    /* vb */
  { 0x52, 0x22 },   /* "matrix coefficient 4" */
  { 0x53, 0x5e },   /* "matrix coefficient 5" */
  { 0x54, 0x80 },   /* "matrix coefficient 6" */
  { REG_COM13, COM13_UVSAT },
  { 0xff, 0xff },   /* END MARKER */
};

const struct regval_list ov7670_default_regs[] PROGMEM = {//from the linux driver
  { REG_COM7, COM7_RESET },
  { REG_TSLB, 0x04 }, /* OV */
  { REG_COM7, 0 },  /* VGA */
  /*
  * Set the hardware window.  These values from OV don't entirely
  * make sense - hstop is less than hstart.  But they work...
  */
  { REG_HSTART, 0x13 }, { REG_HSTOP, 0x01 },
  { REG_HREF, 0xb6 }, { REG_VSTART, 0x02 },
  { REG_VSTOP, 0x7a }, { REG_VREF, 0x0a },

  { REG_COM3, 0 }, { REG_COM14, 0 },
  /* Mystery scaling numbers */
  { 0x70, 0x3a }, { 0x71, 0x35 },
  { 0x72, 0x11 }, { 0x73, 0xf0 },
  { 0xa2,/* 0x02 changed to 1*/1 }, { REG_COM10, 0x0 },
  /* Gamma curve values */
  { 0x7a, 0x20 }, { 0x7b, 0x10 },
  { 0x7c, 0x1e }, { 0x7d, 0x35 },
  { 0x7e, 0x5a }, { 0x7f, 0x69 },
  { 0x80, 0x76 }, { 0x81, 0x80 },
  { 0x82, 0x88 }, { 0x83, 0x8f },
  { 0x84, 0x96 }, { 0x85, 0xa3 },
  { 0x86, 0xaf }, { 0x87, 0xc4 },
  { 0x88, 0xd7 }, { 0x89, 0xe8 },
  /* AGC and AEC parameters.  Note we start by disabling those features,
  then turn them only after tweaking the values. */
  { REG_COM8, COM8_FASTAEC | COM8_AECSTEP },
  { REG_GAIN, 0 }, { REG_AECH, 0 },
  { REG_COM4, 0x40 }, /* magic reserved bit */
  { REG_COM9, 0x18 }, /* 4x gain + magic rsvd bit */
  { REG_BD50MAX, 0x05 }, { REG_BD60MAX, 0x07 },
  { REG_AEW, 0x95 }, { REG_AEB, 0x33 },
  { REG_VPT, 0xe3 }, { REG_HAECC1, 0x78 },
  { REG_HAECC2, 0x68 }, { 0xa1, 0x03 }, /* magic */
  { REG_HAECC3, 0xd8 }, { REG_HAECC4, 0xd8 },
  { REG_HAECC5, 0xf0 }, { REG_HAECC6, 0x90 },
  { REG_HAECC7, 0x94 },
  { REG_COM8, COM8_FASTAEC | COM8_AECSTEP | COM8_AGC | COM8_AEC },
  { 0x30, 0 }, { 0x31, 0 },//disable some delays
  /* Almost all of these are magic "reserved" values.  */
  { REG_COM5, 0x61 }, { REG_COM6, 0x4b },
  { 0x16, 0x02 }, { REG_MVFP, 0x07 },
  { 0x21, 0x02 }, { 0x22, 0x91 },
  { 0x29, 0x07 }, { 0x33, 0x0b },
  { 0x35, 0x0b }, { 0x37, 0x1d },
  { 0x38, 0x71 }, { 0x39, 0x2a },
  { REG_COM12, 0x78 }, { 0x4d, 0x40 },
  { 0x4e, 0x20 }, { REG_GFIX, 0 },
  /*{0x6b, 0x4a},*/{ 0x74, 0x10 },
  { 0x8d, 0x4f }, { 0x8e, 0 },
  { 0x8f, 0 }, { 0x90, 0 },
  { 0x91, 0 }, { 0x96, 0 },
  { 0x9a, 0 }, { 0xb0, 0x84 },
  { 0xb1, 0x0c }, { 0xb2, 0x0e },
  { 0xb3, 0x82 }, { 0xb8, 0x0a },

  /* More reserved magic, some of which tweaks white balance */
  { 0x43, 0x0a }, { 0x44, 0xf0 },
  { 0x45, 0x34 }, { 0x46, 0x58 },
  { 0x47, 0x28 }, { 0x48, 0x3a },
  { 0x59, 0x88 }, { 0x5a, 0x88 },
  { 0x5b, 0x44 }, { 0x5c, 0x67 },
  { 0x5d, 0x49 }, { 0x5e, 0x0e },
  { 0x6c, 0x0a }, { 0x6d, 0x55 },
  { 0x6e, 0x11 }, { 0x6f, 0x9e }, /* it was 0x9F "9e for advance AWB" */
  { 0x6a, 0x40 }, { REG_BLUE, 0x40 },
  { REG_RED, 0x60 },
  { REG_COM8, COM8_FASTAEC | COM8_AECSTEP | COM8_AGC | COM8_AEC | COM8_AWB },

  /* Matrix coefficients */
  { 0x4f, 0x80 }, { 0x50, 0x80 },
  { 0x51, 0 },    { 0x52, 0x22 },
  { 0x53, 0x5e }, { 0x54, 0x80 },
  { 0x58, 0x9e },

  { REG_COM16, COM16_AWBGAIN }, { REG_EDGE, 0 },
  { 0x75, 0x05 }, { REG_REG76, 0xe1 },
  { 0x4c, 0 },     { 0x77, 0x01 },
  { REG_COM13, /*0xc3*/0x48 }, { 0x4b, 0x09 },
  { 0xc9, 0x60 },   /*{REG_COM16, 0x38},*/
  { 0x56, 0x40 },

  { 0x34, 0x11 }, { REG_COM11, COM11_EXP | COM11_HZAUTO },
  { 0xa4, 0x82/*Was 0x88*/ }, { 0x96, 0 },
  { 0x97, 0x30 }, { 0x98, 0x20 },
  { 0x99, 0x30 }, { 0x9a, 0x84 },
  { 0x9b, 0x29 }, { 0x9c, 0x03 },
  { 0x9d, 0x4c }, { 0x9e, 0x3f },
  { 0x78, 0x04 },

  /* Extra-weird stuff.  Some sort of multiplexor register */
  { 0x79, 0x01 }, { 0xc8, 0xf0 },
  { 0x79, 0x0f }, { 0xc8, 0x00 },
  { 0x79, 0x10 }, { 0xc8, 0x7e },
  { 0x79, 0x0a }, { 0xc8, 0x80 },
  { 0x79, 0x0b }, { 0xc8, 0x01 },
  { 0x79, 0x0c }, { 0xc8, 0x0f },
  { 0x79, 0x0d }, { 0xc8, 0x20 },
  { 0x79, 0x09 }, { 0xc8, 0x80 },
  { 0x79, 0x02 }, { 0xc8, 0xc0 },
  { 0x79, 0x03 }, { 0xc8, 0x40 },
  { 0x79, 0x05 }, { 0xc8, 0x30 },
  { 0x79, 0x26 },

  { 0xff, 0xff }, /* END MARKER */
};


void wrSensorRegs8_8(const struct regval_list reglist[]){
    int index = 0;
    regval_list regpaar = reglist[index];

    do {
      write(regpaar.reg_num, regpaar.value); 
      index++;
      regpaar = reglist[index];
    } while (regpaar.reg_num != 0xFF);
}

void setColor(void){
  wrSensorRegs8_8(yuv422_ov7670);
}

void setRes(void){
  write(REG_COM3, 4); // REG_COM3 enable scaling
  wrSensorRegs8_8(qvga_ov7670);
}

#define RESET 33
#define VSYNC 52
#define PCLK 32

#define D8 44
#define D7 45
#define D6 46
#define D5 47
#define D4 48
#define D3 49
#define D2 50
#define D1 51

#define pullup1 22 
#define pullup2 23 

void camInit(void){
  pinMode(RESET, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RESET, HIGH);

  pinMode(pullup1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pullup1, HIGH);

  pinMode(pullup2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pullup2, HIGH);


  write(0x12, 0x80);
  delayMicroseconds(100);
  wrSensorRegs8_8(ov7670_default_regs);
  write(REG_COM10, 32);//PCLK does not toggle on HBLANK.

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);


  pinMode(D1, INPUT);
  pinMode(D2, INPUT);
  pinMode(D3, INPUT);
  pinMode(D4, INPUT);
  pinMode(D5, INPUT);
  pinMode(D6, INPUT);
  pinMode(D7, INPUT);
  pinMode(D8, INPUT);

  pinMode(VSYNC, INPUT);
  pinMode(PCLK, INPUT);
}




void setup() {
  Serial.begin(460800);
  Wire.begin();

  int32_t mask_PWM_pin = digitalPinToBitMask(7);
  REG_PMC_PCER1 = 1<<4;               // activate clock for PWM controller
  REG_PIOC_PDR |= mask_PWM_pin;  // activate peripheral functions for pin (disables all PIO functionality)
  REG_PIOC_ABSR |= mask_PWM_pin; // choose peripheral option B    
  REG_PWM_CLK = 0;                     // choose clock rate, 0 -> full MCLK as reference 84MHz
  REG_PWM_CMR6 = 0<<9;             // select clock and polarity for PWM channel (pin7) -> (CPOL = 0)
  REG_PWM_CPRD6 = 8;                // initialize PWM period -> T = value/84MHz (value: up to 16bit), value=8 -> 10.5MHz
  REG_PWM_CDTY6 = 4;                // initialize duty cycle, REG_PWM_CPRD6 / value = duty cycle, for 8/4 = 50%
  REG_PWM_ENA = 1<<6;               // enable PWM on PWM channel (pin 7 = PWML6)

  camInit();
  setRes();
  setColor();
  write(0x11, 6);
}


void loop() {
  captureImg(320, 480);
}

static void captureImg(uint16_t wg, uint16_t hg){
  uint16_t y, x;

  Serial.println("*RDY*");

  while (!(REG_PIOB_PDSR & (1 << 21)));//wait for high
  while ((REG_PIOB_PDSR & (1 << 21)));//wait for low

  y = hg;
  while (y--){
    x = wg;
    while (x--){
      while ((REG_PIOD_PDSR & (1 << 10)));//wait for low
      myImage[y][x] = (REG_PIOC_PDSR & 0xFF000) >> 12; 
      while (!(REG_PIOD_PDSR & (1 << 10)));//wait for high
      while ((REG_PIOD_PDSR & (1 << 10)));//wait for low
      while (!(REG_PIOD_PDSR & (1 << 10)));//wait for high      
    }
  }

  for (y = 0; y < hg; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < wg; x++) {
      uart_putchar(myImage[y][x]);      
    }
  }
}

void write(uint8_t regID, byte regDat){
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  Wire.write(regID & 0x00FF);    
  Wire.write(regDat & 0x00FF);    

  if(Wire.endTransmission(true)){
    Serial.print("error write reg ");
    Serial.println(regID);
  }
  delay(20);
}


static inline int uart_putchar(const uint8_t c) {
    while(!(UART->UART_SR & UART_SR_TXRDY));
    UART->UART_THR = c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to have stm32 support installed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  better place to ask is https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The (pre)compiler has no idea what `REG_PIOD_PDSR`, `REG_PIOB_PDSR`, etc are. You have to add the proper information (headers, macros, ...), in order to define these "unknown words"

Comment: https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio code, make sure you include the Arduino library at the beginning using

```
#include <Arduino.h>
```

Also in the platformio.ini, make sure the framework is arduino

```
framework = arduino
```

Answer (score -2):

Look at the error. `not declared in this scope` means you didn't declare the variable. For example, there is no `REG_PWM_ENA` defined anywhere, not even in that long list of `#define`s in the start of the file.

Make sure you included all `#include`s from the example you copied, as well as all the `#define`s.